# Loading bulk data into MariaDB with error reporting

Tags: csv, mariadb, bulkinsert

I have a csv file with 10 million records I need to load quickly into a MariaDB database. I am using LOAD DATA INFILE to import the data, however I have one major concern:  error reporting.  It seems LOAD DATA INFILE is very limited in its ability to provide useful feedback on any errors encountered during the file import.  SHOW WARNINGS is limited to 65,535 errors and does not provide a line number for the warnings it provides.  I need to find a solution that is not limited in the number of errors it can potentially provide and that can tell which row number within the csv caused the error.  I haven't been able to find anything in the MariaDB documentation to help.  What is the optimal solution to this dilemma?

Comment: "load quickly" and "manually handle over 65K errors" seem to be at odds with each other??

Comment: @RickJames "quickly" within relative reason.  In short, I need to load this data using the fastest method possible while still maintaining row-level error reporting.

Answer (score 0):

If the errors are empty columns, conversion errors, etc, then I suggest the following instead:

1. `CREATE TABLE` with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` and mostly (or entirely) `VARCHAR(...) NULL` columns.
2. `LOAD DATA` -- this should give no errors?
3. Perform various SQL queries to cleanse the data.  Note that the AI column will be a row number (unless the system is multi-Master).
4. Copy the cleaned up data into the 'real' table with realistic column datatypes.

Comment: I was worried this might be the solution.  My concern here is having to move all that data into the "real" table feels like double work, but if that's the only realistic option I may not have a choice.

Comment: @ryanmovista - This is probably the fastest way to do the entire job.  It gives you "line numbers", mass edits of common "errors", etc.